# How can I get SSL for a Flask app run over Gunicorn?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, flask, https, gunicorn

I run a Flask app over Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04. Gunicorn runs on Port 80. I have NGINX setup, but it isn't used and is disabled. I was able to successfully setup cert-bot for NGINX, but it doesn't help as NGINX isn't used and it also conflicts with gunicorn on Port 80. Is it possible to get a SSL Certificate specifically for Gunicorn/Flask or something that can work with it? SSL and `https` is essential for the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can use certbot generated SSL Certificates with Gunicorn:

1. Follow [certbot instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions) for software "Other". Note the location where generated files are saved.
2. Run Gunicorn and specify certificate and key paths using [--keyfile](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#keyfile) and [--certfile](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#certfile) options. Example:
   `gunicorn --keyfile /some/path/key.pem --certfile /some/path/cert.pem main:app`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to make use of a secure tunnelling service like [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com). With `ngrok`, you can easily tunnel from your `gunicorn` server to a `https` enabled endpoint they provide. Depending on your purpose, this could be a convenient workaround.

Using `ngrok` is as simple as (after [installing](https://ngrok.com/download)):

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:4000
ngrok http 4000
```

This provides you with a secure endpoint like `https://abcd.ngrok.io` that you can send requests to, just the way you'd send requests to your `gunicorn` server.

So `http://0.0.0.0:4000/hello` becomes `https://abcd.ngrok.io/hello`

Answer (score -3):

I'd recommend to change the port for `Gunicorn` to something else, or even bind it to a socket.

Then you can use `Nginx` to handle SSL.

`Gunicorn` offers extensive documentation:

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/index.html

**Update**

DigitalOcean always offers extremely good tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04